# Exception Unable to start activity ComponentInfo when using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using Firbase database and I'm not sure why why this is happening since this is my first time trying it.

I'm getting this exception in my app logcat.

```
03-09 02:39:57.373 15997-15997/com.example.android.clouddatabase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.android.clouddatabase, PID: 15997
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.clouddatabase/com.example.android.clouddatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.clouddatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

This is my build.gradle app file looks like

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.clouddatabase"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
```

I have tried a number of solutions but non of them seemed to work.
so I'm open for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add this to the end of your app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note that in your project level gradle file you should have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'


    }
}
```

It looks like you  don't have a configuration file as well, [here's](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en) how to download it.

Comment: OK and this may sound very elementary, but where should I put it, I tried putting it in the dependencies tag but I'm getting an error

Comment: right at the bottom of you grade file, the last thing in it

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  D:\CloudDatabase\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  D:\CloudDatabase\app\google-services.json

Comment: it seems you didn't configure firebase properly. You need to configure it and download a configuration file called google-services.json

Comment: Thanks, I already downloaded the file but it seems to be in the wrong directory, I moved it now inside the app directory and waiting for the result.

Comment: THANKS!! it is working! I had to create a sub folder in the "app" folder and named it "debug" as proposed in the error message.